# Is there a way to obtain the local socket in use when using URLSession?

Tags: swift, urlsession

I’ve been using URLSession to create a URLSessionStreamTask.  This is sending data to my backend server that is running a custom protocol.  I need to obtain the port number of the local bound socket is there any way to query this?

I’ve looked through the api documentation for URLSession and the URLSessionStreamTask but I’ve not found anything that will tell me the local port.

Comment: How are you creating the `URLSessionStreamTask`? `URLSession streamTask(withHostName:port:)` requires a port so you should already know the port.

Comment: Yep I’m using the streamTask, so I know what the remote port number is but I’m looking for the local socket port number.

Answer (score 0):

In **YourClass** where you have implemented **URLSession** something like below:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
 ....
}
task.delegate = self
task.resume()
```

You can extend the delegate **"URLSessionDataDelegate"**

```
extension YourClass : URLSessionDataDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didFinishCollecting metrics: URLSessionTaskMetrics) {
        for metric in metrics.transactionMetrics {
            print("Local Ip : \(String(describing: metric.localAddress))")
            print("Local port : \(String(describing: metric.localPort))")
        }
    }
}
```